# common block error (padding of bytes) in gfortran

Tags: fortran, fortran-common-block

I am trying to write a fortran code, but when I am trying to pass data from one variable in subroutine to another, error is coming as: 
      common /c/kf,eff,q
                1
Warning: Padding of 4 bytes required before 'q' in COMMON 'c' at (1); reorder elements or use -fno-align-commons.

The value of q from subroutine input to calculation is not being passed. 
If the value of q at subroutine input is 5e-3, the value of q at subroutine calculation is 3.57e-315

Kindly help

See the code

```
    implicit none
    call input
    call calculation
    stop
    end

    subroutine input
    real*8 n
    real*8 l1,l2,l3,d,kf,eff,z1,z2,rho,mu,pin,pout,l4
    common /a/l1,l2,l3,l4,d
    common /c/kf,eff,q
    common /e/z1,z2
    common /d/rho,mu,pin,pout
    common /b/n
    print*,"enter the lengths of the pipe at various sections (4)"
    read(*,*) l1,l2,l3,l4
    print*,"enter the diameter of the pipe"
    read(*,*) d
    print*,"enter the volumetric flow rate (m3/s)"
    read(*,*) q
    print*,"enter the number of elbows to be added"
    read(*,*) n
    print*,"enter firction coefficient for elbow"
    read(*,*) kf
    print*,"enter the pump efficiency"
    read(*,*) eff
    print*,"enter the datum height (m)"
    read(*,*)z1
    print*,"enter the final height (m)"
    read(*,*)z2
    print*,"enter the density of the fluid (kg/m3)"
    read(*,*)rho
    print*,"enter the viscosity of the fluid (kg/ms)"
    read(*,*)mu
    print*,"enter the inlet and exit pressure (KPa)"
    read(*,*) pin,pout
    print*,q
    end

    subroutine calculation
    real*8 n
    real*8 g,pi,v2,v1,vdif,z2,z1,head,v,q,d
    real*8 p,pout,pin,rho,re,mu,f,kc,hc,kf,hf
    real*8 kex,hex,l,l1,l2,l3,l4,fp,ft,Ws,Wp,m,power
    common /a/l1,l2,l3,l4,d
    common /c/kf,eff,q
    common /e/z1,z2
    common /d/rho,mu,pin,pout
    common /b/n
    parameter (g=9.8,pi=3.14)
    print*,q,d
    v= (4*q)!/(pi*(d**2))
    v1=v
    v2=v
    vdif=0.5*((v2**2)-(v1**2))
    head=g*(z2-z1)
    p=(pout-pin)/(rho)
    re=(d*v*rho)/(mu)
    print*,v,vdif,p,head,re
    if (re>2000)  then
    f=16/re
    else
    f=0.079*(re**(-0.25))
    endif
    kc=0.55                        
    hc=kc*(v**2)/2
    hf=n*kf*(v**2)/2           
    kex=1                          
    hex=kex*(v**2)/2
    l=l1+l2+l3+l4                 
    fp=(4*f*l*(v**2))/(2*d)
    ft=hc+hf+hex+fp
    Ws=-head-vdif-ft
    Wp=-(Ws/eff)                   
    m=q*rho                        
    power=m*Wp
    print*, "the power required by the pump is", power
    end
```

Comment: Using `implicit none` everywhere would be the first thing to do.

Comment: Welcome. Please take the Welcome [tour]. `IMPLICIT NONE` should really be used everywhere. Also note that common blocks ate obsolete in this century and modern Fortran uses modules.

Comment: implicit none has been used in the main program

Comment: Use it, in your case, also in the subroutines, it is not 'exported` from the main program to the subroutine.

Comment: Just to back up Vladimir nobody should have written a new common block in 25 years. Either put the variables in appropriate modules, or better use modules to define appropriate derived types and pass them as arguments

Comment: Modules cannot be used in fortran 77, right?
Modules can be used only for fortran 90, please suggest me a good book

Comment: Metcalf, Reid and Cohen "Modern Fortran Explained" https://www.amazon.co.uk/Explained-Numerical-Mathematics-Scientific-Computation/dp/0199601429

Comment: COMMON blocks still have a place as it is how you can easily write a Fortran program that uses shared memory (multi-processing). Otherwise I very much agree they should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn’t look like you define variable q as real*8 in subroutine input. You don’t specify implicit none in the input subroutine, so it’ll be implicitly declared real*4. That means your common blocks are mapping out two different regions in memory starting from the same initial memory address. Fortran interprets memory in common blocks according to the variable types and their order. That means in one subroutine q is a double and in the other it’s a float. That’s why you’re getting the value change.